# Some shows/movies in my tv/movie app do not have posters. How do I write a ternary statement that shows a message if no image is found?

Tags: javascript, html, api

```html
<div class="trendingItem" data-id="${item.id}" data-type="${item.media_type}">
            <a href="#" id="viewItem" class="viewItem">
              <img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item.backdrop_path}' loading="lazy" alt="movie poster"/>
            </a>
            <h4>${item.title ? item.title : item.name}</h4>
</div>
```

So this is my code and I trying to do a ternary statement that basically says if there is no image then insert a message saying no image found but I am not sure how to do that.

**Update:**

This is what I tried but so far it doesn't work.

```
<div class="trendingItem" data-id="${item.id}" data-type="${item.media_type}">
            <a href="#" id="viewItem" class="viewItem">
              <img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item.backdrop_path} ? ${item.backdrop_path} : <h4>No Image Found</h4>' loading="lazy" alt="movie poster"/>
            </a>
            <h4>${item.title ? item.title : item.name}</h4>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Based on your treatment of `item.title`, you know how to write a ternary

Comment: So this is what I tried. `<img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item.backdrop_path} ? ${item.backdrop_path} : <h4>No Image Found</h4>' loading="lazy" alt="movie poster"/>` but it is incorrect because it doesn't show the <h4> with the message

Comment: Please update your question to put your codes.

Comment: You cannot put a `<h4>` element within the image `src` attribute. Your ternary will need to result in the entire `<img>` or `<h4>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML is within a JavaScript template literal and you only want to show the image if `item.backdrop_path` is *truthy*, you'll need to have your ternary statement evaluate to either `<img>` or `<h4>` element in their entirety.

```js
const html = `
  <div class="trendingItem" data-id="${item.id}" data-type="${item.media_type}">
    <a href="#" id="viewItem" class="viewItem">
      ${item.backdrop_path
        ? `<img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item.backdrop_path}" loading="lazy" alt="movie poster"/>`
        : "<h4>No Image Found</h4>"
      }
    </a>
    <h4>${item.title ? item.title : item.name}</h4>
  </div>
`.trim();
```

---

I strongly advise against creating strings of HTML. Instead, use the DOM methods to create actual elements

```js
const createElement = (tag, attributes, ...children) => {
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  Object.entries(attributes ?? {}).forEach(([attr, val]) => {
    el.setAttribute(attr, val);
  });
  el.append(...children);
  return el;
};

const div = createElement(
  "div",
  { class: "trendingItem", "data-id": item.id, "data-type": item.media_type },
  createElement(
    "a",
    { href: "#", id: "viewItem", class: "viewItem" },
    item.backdrop_path
      ? createElement("img", {
          src: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item.backdrop_path}`,
          loading: "lazy",
          alt: "movie poster",
        })
      : createElement("h4", null, "No Image Found"),
  ),
  createElement("h4", null, item.title ?? item.name)
);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Yeah I just find createelement a bit more overwhelming to use but I do plan on switching to it once I am a bit more familar/comfortable with it.